# By using loop controller how add multiple items to cart by using single request of jpetstore application in searchbar

Tags: jmeter

How to add multiple products in cart by using loop controller in jpetstore application and by using one request we need add multiple items to cart

Just normally trying in jmeter

Answer (score 1):

[Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) basically executes its child(ren) defined number of times.

I don't know whether it's 100% suitable for adding items to cart, my expectation is that you need to pass the ID of the item you're adding to the cart which means that you need to determine this ID somehow, i.e. open the list of the items and use a relevant [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) like [Regular Expression Extractor or Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor)

[image]

This way you will get the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

```
ItemID_1=foo
ItemID_2=bar
etc.
ItemID_matchNr=2
```

If you want to add all the items - then put `${ItemID_matchNr}` as the Loop Count of the Loop Controller

[image]

and use [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) functions combination in the HTTP Request sampler to refer the current ItemId like:

```
${__V(ItemId_${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)},)}
```

where required:

[image]